# Database Schema Design (Visio Forward engineering error) : Child columns form a key

Tags: sql, database-design

I've build a Database Molde Diagram in Visio 2010 and am trying to Forward engineer the diagram as Schema.

I'm stuck on fixing the following warnings i get:

```
 warning : 'User_Screen_SCREENS_FK1' : Relationship has cardinality other than either zero-or-one or exactly-one, yet the child columns form a key.
```

The two table in question are below:

[image]

The `Screens` table is where i store all the "Screens" available in this application, `User_Screens` is used to controls screens a user has access to. (there is separate `Users` table which has a `1 to 0 or more` relationship `User_Screen`).

I am not sure where the problem is and how to fix it? Would anyone be able to tell me where I've gone wrong?

### UPDATE:

modified the relationship and included all related table to better illustrate the problem in image below:

[image]

Errors i have:

```
 error : 'User_Screen_SCREENS_FK1' : Child column(s) not specified.
```

Warnings i cant get rid off:

```
warning : 'POSITION_USERS_FK1' : Relationship has a cardinality of either zero-or-one or exactly-one, yet the child columns form part of a key.

 warning : 'User_Screen_SCREENS_FK1' : Child columns overlap with child columns of USERS_SCREENS_FK1.

 warning : 'USERS_SCREENS_FK1' : Relationship has cardinality other than either zero-or-one or exactly-one, yet the child columns form a key.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's confused because you're trying to add a PK from each table as a FK in each table.  Try giving each table a single PK, a basic autonumber INT, and elimnate your multi-column primary keys:

**Screens**: PK: ScreenID INT | FK: PositionID

**Positions**: PK: PositionID INT | PositionName VARCHAR

**User_Screens**: PK: UserScreenID INT | FK: UserID | FK: ScreenID

This splits the screen-level information and the user-level information: for example, you don't need the positionID in both tables (if I understand what that means), it just belongs to the screen.  You can get the position information from your join.  This would give you all screen positions for a given User:

```
SELECT [PositionName] FROM UserScreens t1 JOIN Screens t2 ON t1.ScreenID = t2.ScreenID JOIN Positions t3 ON t2.PositionID = t3.PositionID WHERE t1.UserID = 12345
```

---

UPDATE: you're still defining too many foreign keys where they aren't necessary.  For example, the Screens table doesn't need a FK on UserPK because the UserScreens table is going to be the link between them.    Ignoring non-PK and non-FK fields:

```
[Users]: UserPK
[Screens]: ScreenPK, PositionPK_FK
[UserScreen]: UserScreenPK, UserPK_FK, ScreenPK_FK
```

If the position can change between users, MOVE the PositionPK_FK to [UserScreen].

Comment: thanks for the comments. I changed the relationship structure (see updated question) and tried your suggestions but Visio doesn't liek the changes and make the relationship marked as invalid (dotted line)

Comment: The Position table should only be linked with the Screen table, OR with the UserScreen table if the position can change based on the user.  The Screens table needs a PK, and that needs to be a FK on the UserScreens table.  The User PK should ONLY be a FK on the UserLogin and UserScreens table - remove the FK from Screens.

Comment: Users table should not have any FKs.